# Mapping data from two dictionary and make a resultant one with specific format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a two dictionaries:

`featurePermissionMap = {'2':2,'3':1,'4':1}` where key is the feature id and it's value represents the permission type.
Like `'2':2` means for a feature id 2 we have a permission 2(Read and Write)
and `'3':1` means for a feature id 3 we have a permission 1(Read-Only)

**Second Dictionary:**

```
feature_with_sub_feature = 
[
{ name: 'FeatureA', 
  subfeatures: [
   { id: 2, name: 'Feature2' },
   { id: 3, name: 'Feature3' },
},
.......
];
```

**I need a resultant dictionary like below:**

```
read_write_access_feature = {
  'read':{},
  'write':{}
}
```

I just want to iterate over feature_with_sub_feature and based on subfeature id, I want output like

```
read_write_access_feature = {
  'read':{'FeatureA':['Feature3',....],......},
  'write':{'FeatureA':['Feature2',.....],....}
}
```

I am trying to achieve this using the two forEach. I am new to javascript.
Any optimized way would be much appreciated.

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you have a more complete data sets and the wanted result of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added function `getFeatureWithPermission` which will `return features with permission passed in parameter`. Added code explanation in comment.

call `getFeatureWithPermission` will required `permission` as below.

```
let read_write_access_feature = {
  'read': getFeatureWithPermission(1),
  'write': getFeatureWithPermission(2)
};
```

Try it below.

```js
let featurePermissionMap = {'2': 2, '3': 1, '4': 1};

// return features with permission passed in parameter.
function getFeatureWithPermission(permission) {
  // use reduce to update & return object as requiment
  return feature_with_sub_feature.reduce((a, x) => {
    // return object with key as x.name
    // value as array of names from subfeatures which have respective permission
    // first filter subfeatures for respective permission
    // then use map to select only name from subfeatures
    a[x.name] = x.subfeatures
        .filter(y => featurePermissionMap[y.id] === permission)
        .map(y => y.name);
    return a;
  }, {}); // <- pass empty object as input
}


let feature_with_sub_feature =  [{ 
  name: 'FeatureA', 
  subfeatures: [
    { id: 2, name: 'Feature2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Feature3' },
  ]
}];

let read_write_access_feature = {
  'read': getFeatureWithPermission(1),
  'write': getFeatureWithPermission(2)
};

console.log(read_write_access_feature);
```